# Why pilots would leave the cockpit in a short flight?

Tags: airline-operations, pilots, airline-pilot

I've occasionally read about [pilots being locked out of the cockpit](http://www.cnn.com/2015/01/30/travel/feat-delta-captain-lockout/) in flight, and was wondering:

Why might a pilot leave the cockpit during a short flight (1-2 hours)?

Comment: And when you read about pilots being locked out of the cockpit, the article didn't mention why they'd left?

Comment: Just from a human standpoint:  You have to pee, when you have to pee. While the bladder reached a regular "time interval", "much liquied" (everybody should drink on a plane due dry air or you become easily sick), "being nervous" or because your bladder doesn't work normally (ill). Furthermore like all humans a crew needs to stand up and move their feet (again, it healthy and keeps awake) and chat a little bit with the crew. As passanger I would appreciate to see that the pilots have a little bit contact to the rest of humanity on the plane :)

Answer (score 41):

The cockpit of some airliners lacks a lavatory.

[[image]

<sup>*Cockpit layout from AviationKnowledge.wikidot*</sup>](http://aviationknowledge.wikidot.com/aviation:cockpit-airplane)

---

This is discussed in [Skybrary: Flight Deck Security](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Deck_Security)

> Locked Door Flight Safety Issues
>   ...
>   Physiological Need. Naturally, the need for flight crew to use toilets, access designated crew rest facilities or be supplied with food and drink, requires access through the flight deck door during flight. Procedures for door opening mean that egress and access will take longer with the result that the flight deck crew are not always able to go to the toilet at a time of their exact choice, which may cause them to be distracted and, exceptionally, might exacerbate an existing underlying medical issue in a way that would not otherwise have occurred.
>   ...
>   Longer term, design change could also ensure that all operating flight crew should be secured on the flight-deck before the passenger boarding doors are closed prior to departure and remain secured on the flight-deck until after the passenger doors are opened at the destination. This would prevent any unlawful entry from the cabin and minimise any unlawful seizure by a single flight crew member.
>   To enable this, existing aircraft could be modified and new aircraft designed with all required crew facilities forward of the secure flight-deck door. On short/medium haul aircraft this would require a toilet, safe food & water storage and a reclining crew rest seat. Additionally on aircraft used for long range operations where in-flight relief is required provision of bunk/s.
>   This is not a new concept, many long range aircraft already have toilet and crew rest facilities forward of the secure flight-deck door.

Comment: Do you have to pee in a 90 min. flight?

Comment: @JuanMateo no, but you probably have to pee sometime during the day, and with the short turnaround times, I'm pretty sure there's no chance to do so on the ground

Comment: When you've gotta go you've gotta go, and I'd much rather have a pilot who can fully concentrate on landing the plane than one who's trying to hold it in.

Comment: 90 min is a wrong assumption. First, the flight was 2h20' long, second there are pre-flight and post-flight duties, that would make it longer.

Comment: Is there an actual image of a toilet inside the cockpit. Also can't the pilot's use Travel John?

Comment: @JuanMateo middle of a flight would probably be the best time to take a pee, since on the ground in pre-flight and post-flight duties the pilots are busy, but while the plane is cruising on a straight path then there's practically nothing to do and a single pilot can easily handle it - I mean, it's the appropriate time for pilots to take a nap in longer trips.

Comment: @Firee Notice that the door to the toilet in that image opens to outside the flight deck (i.e. to the passenger cabin.) Most airliners don't have dedicated lavs for the pilots. That would be a really big waste of space and weight.

Comment: @reirab : Why can't they provide a door to the lavatory from the inside, so that the pilots don't have to leave the confines of the cockpit..

Comment: @Firee They could, but that would then make the lav a second potential point of access to the flight deck, which is probably more dangerous, as someone could attempt to break in without being noticed until they've already gained access to the flight deck. Additionally, there's not much extra space for another door either in the lav or on the flight deck in most aircraft. For example, in the diagram above, the sink is on the one side of the wall between the lav and the cockpit and the circuit breakers are on the others side, so both would have to move (and there's no extra room for the sink.)

Comment: @Firee Granted, in the particular configuration shown in the image above, access to the flight deck probably isn't as critical, since it's presumably a military aircraft (civilian transports typically don't have a station for an air-to-air refueling operator.)

Comment: Why having toilets in theaters for a 90 min movie? Or in tube? Why should pilots be forbidden to have prostate problems like the rest of the people? Wait until you're 55 and you'll likely understand.

Comment: @reirab: Maybe some kind of solution similar to fighter aircraft pilots, could be looked at

Comment: @Firee I'm thinking the pilots would not like that. Especially not the female pilots. Why bother when there's a perfectly good lav a few feet away? Incidents like the Germanwings flight can be solved [by having an FA take the place of a pilot when he leaves the flight deck](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13526/755). This has been standard procedure for a lot of U.S. airlines for a long time and has, in the wake of the Germanwings incident, also become recommended practice in Europe.

Answer (score 24):

The FAA provides the following reasons for which a pilot is allowed to leave their assigned duty station (i.e. their seat in the flight deck) in [14 CFR §121.543 Flight crewmembers at controls](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=se14.3.121_1543):

> (b) A required flight crewmember may leave the assigned duty station—
>
> (1) If the crewmember's absence is necessary for the performance of duties in connection with the operation of the aircraft;
>
> (2) If the crewmember's absence is in connection with physiological needs; or
>
> (3) If the crewmember is taking a rest period, and relief is provided—

Case #3 generally applies only to long-haul flights where one or two relief pilots will alternate duty with the initial pilots, allowing each of them to have a rest period.

Europe's EASA has similar regulations. See [CAT.OP.MPA.210 in this document](https://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Annexes%20to%20Regulation.pdf) (on pages 101-102).

> CAT.OP.MPA.210 Crew members at stations
>
> (a) Flight crew members
>
> (1) During take-off and landing each flight crew member required to be on duty in the flight crew compartment shall be at the assigned station.
>
> (2) During all other phases of flight each flight crew member required to be on duty in the flight crew compartment shall remain at the assigned station, unless absence is necessary for the performance of duties in connection with the operation or for physiological needs, provided at least one suitably qualified pilot remains at the controls of the aircraft at all times.

---

So, in summary, a pilot can leave the flight deck on short flights if:

1) The pilot needs to go to the bathroom.

2) The pilot needs to perform some action relevant to flying the plane (such as going to the back to physically inspect some part of the plane, like in [QF32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32) or [United 811](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_811).)

Related question whose answers also mentions these regs: [Are two people required in the cockpit at all times on large commercial aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13526/755)

Comment: Might want to at least link to the question where this is info is also used.

Comment: @fooot Honestly, I was trying to decide whether to vote dupe close on this one. However, those answer really answer this question, but _not the one they're posted on_, so I wasn't really sure how to address that. Nevertheless, I'll add a link.

Comment: Well those regulations don't totally answer whether a second crew member is required at all times (just that it's not in the general operating rules), but they don't provide all the exact reasons a pilot may leave the cockpit either. Thanks for adding the link.