# Which air transport aircraft have a lavatory included inside the cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner

Another answer on SE Aviation ([Why pilots would leave the cockpit in a short flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/why-pilots-would-leave-the-cockpit-in-a-short-flight)
) had this bit of information in it:

> The cockpit of some airliners lacks a lavatory.

Isn't is more the other way around: i.e. A Lavatory inside a cockpit is a rarity?

Which airliner cockpits have an entire Lavatory **inside** them?

I always thought the Flight Crew came out to use the forward-most Business / First class lavatory.

Comment: http://www.wilfredasuquo.com/2015/03/just-my-imagination-as-pilot-toilet-in.html?m=1

Comment: I suppose it depends on how the airline orders the aircraft. Although with the secured cockpits I wouldn't be surprised if it is becoming more common

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, some Boeing 747-400s (BA, Air France) had lavatories inside the cockpit. Apparently, Boeing 747-8 Intercontinental [has a lavatory behind the cockpit door](http://airwaysnews.com/html/cabins-and-cockpits/lufthansa/lufthansa-boeing-747-8-intercontinental-flight-deck-and-flight-attendant-crew-quarters-2012/20861):

> ... Lufthansa Boeing 747-8 Intercontinental is unique in that the flight deck crew have their own lavatory, ... behind the locked cockpit door, allowing for extra security and a non-disruptive cabin service involving trolleys blocking the door.